# find character and join these line with the next

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a text like:

```
         1,
00€
         2,
22€
         1,
12
```

How could I get:

```
1,00€
2,22€
1,12€
```

I'm trying with bash but I can't.

Comment: Because bash isn't a text editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/,$/ { N; s/\n//; s/^\s\+//; }' file
```

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk '/,$/ { s = $1; getline; print s $1 }' file
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe 's/^\s+//; $_ .= <>; chomp' file
```

Comment: By using `[[:space:]]*` instead of `\s\+` you can use the code with any `sed`, GNU or other.

Comment: @Philippos POSIX `sed` doesn't necessarily know about `\n`, either.

Comment: Says who? "*The escape sequence '\n' shall match a <newline> embedded in the pattern space*." says [open group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

Comment: @Philippos Says my past experience with supposedly POSIX `sed`s. :) Back in the days you had to embed actual newlines in patterns for that.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Note that `\n` is accepted on the `lhs` of `s///` but not on the `rhs` for a `POSIX`-sed.